# Class has error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required

Tags: c#

There are many answers for this common error, but the ones I have looked at don't solve this specific problem.
I have the following inheritance;

```
public class C : B
{
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public B(string id, string name, JObject parameters) : base(parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is;

```
CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'id' of B.B(String, String, JObject)
```

To fix it VS suggests the following the following constructor;

```
public C(string id, string name, JObject parameters):
        base(id, name, parameters) { }
```

Why is the C constructor required when all it does is to pass the values to B? I would have thought that if I had not overriden the inherited constructor that I do not have to define it again.
If a class does not define a constructor it is assumed that a parameter-less one will exist. However, if it inherits from a class with a parameterized constructor shouldn't that then be the assumption?

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited in C#

Comment: Your question is exactly the same as the marked duplicate. Just replace your `C` with `B` and your `B` with `A`. Your `C` is trying to call the only constructor in your `B`, which requires an `id` (and `name` and `parameters`), but your `C` didn't provide one. Hence the error. You have to either pass values, or put a parameterless constructor in `B` (as described in the marked duplicate).

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks. I didn't realize that C would have an implicit parameter-less constructor I thought it would default to the base class' constructor signature. But  now I realize that wouldn't work when inheriting from multiple bases. How do I flag this for moderation? I can't delete it with answers.

Comment: Looks like there are [too many answers and up-votes on the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) to delete your question. But you don't need to if you don't want. Sometimes, having a ["sign post"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) duplicate is helpful to the site. If you still want to delete it, just click the **flag** link at the bottom of your post. Submit a custom flag. Be _specific_ about what you want the moderator to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B` only has *one* constructor, the one that takes three arguments. `C` is currently using its default constructor (it doesn't magically get `B`'s constructor), which could be explicitly written:

```
public C(): base()
{ }
```

However, that base constructor *does not exist*. At the very least you need to use the correct base constructor (now requiring you to define it):

```
public C(): base(id, name, parameters)
{ }
```

Except now you are using undeclared variables. You could just pass the default values for those, but VS puts them in C's parameter list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Refer back to the A Class Constructor as you are calling the base constructor on the class B which obviously does not match the the constructor parameters for the class A