# The method takes hold of the database all the time?

Tags: c#

That's how I call the class in the area I'm going to work with, so I can not move on because it's just like the database area.

How might it be that area? So, it does think like the whole time it's the database I want to get?

It is in relation to a previous question that I have quiet in this regard.

_Layout.cshtml

```
@{
    var menuModel = new NewWebsite_Site_2018.Pages.View.ViewBar_Info.MenuModel();
}
```

Menu.cshtml.cs

```
public class MenuModel : PageModel
{
    public List<ContentInfo> GetListMenu { get; set; }


    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public MenuModel(DBContext context) : base()
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        GetListMenu = _dbContext.ContentInfo.Where(i => i.ShowMenu == true).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
    }
}
}
```

That's how I want to get in GetListMenu. It's just the one I need to move on.

i have read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846763/class-has-error-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required)

Error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'context' of 'MenuModel.MenuModel(DBContext)'

Comment: That error message is telling you that can't call `MenuModel()` with no arguments; which is what you're doing when you try to set the value of `var menuModel`.  Change that method call to include the DBContext argument.

Comment: Okay i can see what y mean. But u can see here what i need to make: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644916/9053235

Comment: How do you think I should move on? @Gus